# Weird behavior with android Oreo and onclick

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have an application that use a hand Barcode scanner. I test the app in android 5.1 and works good, but in Android Oreo there is a weird behavior with onClick method.

1. The app start and I start to scan products. (The method dispatchKeyEvent is called in order to get the barcode).
2. I touch the screen
3. I continue scanning and dispatchKeyEvent of my activity and onClick method in my fragment are executed.

I don't understand why.

In My MainActivity I receive all the barcode scanned and send to my fragment:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {

        getUpcScanned(e);
        upcScannedAlreadyFinished(e);

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
    }

 public void getUpcScanned(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            char pressedKey = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
            upcScanned += pressedKey;
        }
    }

 private void upcScannedAlreadyFinished(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            SelfScanGlobalContext.getInstance().setScrollNeedsToMove(false);
            fragmentHopper.showShoppingCartFragment(upcScanned.trim(), presenterForFragment);
            upcScanned="";
            if(this.presenterForFragment!=null){
                this.presenterForFragment.onUserInteraction();
            }
        }
    }
```

In My fragment

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("On activity created......");
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Button cancelPurchaseBtn = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cancelPurchaseBtnTest);
        cancelPurchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


 @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.cancelPurchaseBtnTest :
                AlertDialogHopper.createCancelTransactionDialog(this);
                break;
        }
    }
```

I only have one onUserInteraction() that resets a timer every time an event occurs.

After touch, both methods are called. I think that is something related to the barcode scanner.

Comment: I don't necessarily know that this is your problem, but can you verify in android 8.0 that your keypress event is doing as expected?  I've heard that getting the enter keypress is inconsistent depending on which keyboard is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OnClick event is not just triggered from pressing on your button.  It merely needs focus when an enter key is pressed.  To prevent the behavior you are seeing, you need to change the listener on your buttons to OnTouch (from View.OnTouchListener) which will only get triggered if you physically press the button.  Accessibility differences in the versions of android could be causing the behavior you are seeing because the first button on the layout automatically has focus.  It could even be differences in the keyboard doing it.

Comment: You're right, I changed my event to OnTouchListener and the app works good. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Putting as an answer because I do not have the rep to comment.

Your issue may be with something called 'Scan Wedge' this essentially uses the scanner as a keyboard and will automatically input data into an on-focus field (i.e. an editText in android). It doesn't actually call your code it's something built into the SDK's and API's given by these barcode scanner companies, generally you can turn these off programatically.

My only other suggestion is to println() or something in your onClick method, or any other method to see what is being called, when and where

Comment: I was debugging, and it's very weird, because in my fragment I have 2 buttons, and when I touch the screen and onClick and dispatchKeyEvent are executed, in the onClick method the  view.getId() is only the first button of my layout, the app is detecting both methods like keypress.

Comment: so you're saying view.getId is returning the wrong button?

Comment: @JohnLord  No really, I don’t know why the view.getId is returning the first id button that I have,

Comment: @JonhLord The correct thing would be that this doesn’t return any id because I am not pressing any button

Comment: Have you looked in your XML code to see if both of your buttons in the fragment are implementing 'onClick'? 

It looks like this within the XML.
android:onClick="classMethod"

Comment: I suggest you change your event then to OnTouch since onClick could be triggered from the keyboard.